# Prove that if $f^2 = 0_{E}$ and $n = 2\operatorname{rank} f$ then $\operatorname{im} f = \ker f$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> $\DeclareMathOperator\rank{rank}\DeclareMathOperator\im{im}$Let $f$ be a linear map from $E$ unto $E$.
>
> $E$ is a vector space that has dimension $n$.
>
> Prove that the following two statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. $f^2 = 0_{E}$ ($0_{E}$ is the zero map) and $n = 2\rank(f)$
> 2. $\im f = \ker f$

---

I proved $(2) \implies (1)$

From rank-nullity theorem we have: $ \dim \im f + \dim \ker f = n $

$\implies \dim \im f + \dim \im f = n $ (because $\im f = \ker f$).

$\implies n = 2\rank(f) $

Also We have: $x \in \im f \implies x \in \ker f \implies f(x) = 0 \implies f^2(x) = f(0) = 0$

I don't know how to prove $ (1) \implies (2) $.

Is my first argument correct? How can I prove the other way?

Comment: For 1. implies 2., observe that the image is a subspace of the kernel.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown From $f^2 = 0$ we have $Im f  \subset Kerf$. To get the equality, than I need to prove $Kerf \subset Imf$. I don't see how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument for $(2) \implies (1)$ is fine.

For the other implication, note that $f^2=0$ implies $\text{Im}(f)\subset\ker(f)$.  Thus $\dim\ker(f)\geq\text{rank}(f)$, so we have 
$$n=\text{rank}(f)+\dim\ker(f)\geq2\cdot\text{rank}(f)=n.$$
so equality holds, and thus $\text{rank}(f)=\dim\ker(f)$.  What can you infer from this?

Comment: To get $Im(f) = Ker(f)$, we need to prove the other inclusion $Ker(f) \subset Im(f)$.  Which I could not see how to get from your inequality.

Comment: Does my edit help at all?

Comment: I don't know if we can pass from $rank(f) = \dim ker(f)$ to $Im(f) = Ker(f)$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? Thank you

Comment: Well if $x\in\ker(f)\setminus\text{Im}(f)$ and $\{e_1,\ldots,e_m\}$ is a basis of $\text{Im}(f)$, then $\{x,e_1,\ldots,e_m\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $\ker(f)$.  But then $\dim\ker(f)\geq m+1>m=\text{rank}(f)=\dim\ker(f)$, a contradiction.

Comment: This is part of a more general phenomenon:  If $U$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$ and $\dim U=\dim V<\infty$, then $U=V$.